# flutter - jitse_meet plugin video call functionality not working in release mode , app crashed when start video call

Tags: android, flutter, jitsi-meet, release-mode, videocall

I added all the configuration that need for the jitsi_meet sdk . It will working in the debug mode but when I tr to run in the relase mode it will crash the app.

this is function that I used to start video call

```
              makeCall() async { 
           // it is use for init the meeting with jitsi-meet plugin
            await JitsiMeet.joinMeeting(
              options,
              listener: JitsiMeetingListener(
                  onConferenceWillJoin: (message) {
                    debugPrint(
                        "ConferenceTesting:-   Inner  ${options.room} will join with message: $message");
                  },
                  onConferenceJoined: (message) {
                    debugPrint(
                        "ConferenceTesting:-  Inner  ${options.room} joined with message: $message");
                  },
                  onConferenceTerminated: (message) {
                    debugPrint(
                        "ConferenceTesting:-  Inner   ${options.room} terminated with message: $message");
                    chatHistoryController.updateCallStatus(
                        widget.data!.id!, Utils.EVENT_TYPE_CALL_ENDED);
                  },
                  genericListeners: [
                    JitsiGenericListener(
                        eventName: 'readyToClose',
                        callback: (dynamic message) {
                          debugPrint("ConferenceTesting: readyToClose callback");
                        }),
                    JitsiGenericListener(
                        eventName: 'participantJoined',
                        callback: (dynamic message) {
                          debugPrint("ConferenceTesting: participantJoined callback");
                        }),
                  ]),
            );
          }
```

Error Logs :-
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libreactnativejni.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libyoga.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libfb.so caused by: com.facebook.jni.HybridData$Destructor
E/AndroidRuntime(13965):    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.b(:6)
E/AndroidRuntime(13965):    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.i(Unknown Source:86)
E/AndroidRuntime(13965):    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.g(:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(13965):    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.staticInit(:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(13965):    at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeMap.(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(13965):    at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.a.create(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(13965):    at h.e.m.j$b.run(Unknown Source:58)
E/AndroidRuntime(13965):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919

Comment: Did you add internet permission to your manifest file?

Comment: yes @AbbasJafari I added the internet permission.